# Troubles with creation of nested dictionaries in swift

Tags: swift

I'm learning swift and tried to create simple (as in js) dictionary, which will keep values from incoming json.

```
var QUOTES: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>
var data: [Dictionary<String,Any>] = [
    ["ticker": "AAPL", "price": 100, "name": "Apple Company", "some": "something"],
    ["ticker": "F", "price": 150, "name": "Ford Company"],
    ["ticker": "FB", "price": 1000, "name": "Facebook Company"],
]

for quote in data {
    var ticker = quote["ticker"] as! String

    for (key, value) in quote {
        QUOTES[ticker][key] = value //it fails with error
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Value of optional type '[String : Any]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

I've read everything I could on unwrapping values, but putting `!` doesnt help.

**What should I do to fill desired Dictionary?**

Comment: `quote` has type `(key: String, value: Any)`. That's probably not what you intended.

Comment: You should make an array of a new `struct` or `class` to model your data, instead of having an array of dictionaries. Dictionaries don't work well with heterogeneously typed data like this.